# Why did I just get a 22 day old post in the First Post review queue?

Tags: bug, review

Just now I completed a [First Post review task](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/427883) for a 22 day old question (and the review was not an audit). Why did this happen?

I was under the impression that posts are stuck in the review queue soon after they are posted, so the only reason I can think of for this occurrence is that someone left the review task open in their browser for a great deal of time, and that tab has only just been killed. Is this possible? Is there some other explanation?

Comment: Link to the review in question: http://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/427883

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks! I was just trying to figure out how to get that link

Comment: You can find links to the recent reviews [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history). If you know who reviewed it, you might use that user's [activity tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/145826/peter-woolfitt?tab=activity). For finding older reviews, [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/208490/find-the-reviews-for-a-post?postid=1147668) might be useful. (I learned about that SEDE query [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165?m=20178143#20178143).)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know the code, so I can't be absolutely sure, but I think the following is what happened:

This was not the first question the user asked on the site. A question they asked previously was deleted about an hour ago, making this the only, and hence first, post of that user visible on the site. Thus far, I'm certain that that is what happened. The code found a "first post" that was not yet reviewed [this is the speculative part], and thus enqueued it in the "First Posts" queue (about five minutes after the deletion), where you found and reviewed it.

Comment: This answer suggests that your speculation seems reasonable: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235024/old-first-post-reviews-on-sites-without-audits-enabled/235034#235034