# Late reviewing of late answer

Tags: discussion, review

In a recent late answer review I saw this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/441402), which is six month's old. What took it so long to come to the review queue?

There's a similar issue for [first post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20711/why-did-i-just-get-a-22-day-old-post-in-the-first-post-review-queue) and I understand that mechanism. But it seems that the argument does not apply here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [Grace Note's answer on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222413), answers are put into the late-answer review queue when the following conditions are satisfied

1. the answer was posted at least 30 days after the question was asked, and
2. the answer was posted by a user who has 10 or less reputation (disregarding suspension).

In particular, it does not check the reputation of the user *at the time of posting* nor *how old the answer is*, so that a user with, say, 11 reputation can post an answer to a two-and-a-half year old question, have no reputation changes for a couple years, receive a downvote dropping them to 9 reputation, and then have their years old answer put into the queue.